# Put large ndarrays fast to multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When trying to put a large `ndarray` to a `Queue` in a `Process`, I encounter the following problem:

First, here is the code:

```
import numpy
import multiprocessing
from ctypes import c_bool
import time


def run(acquisition_running, data_queue):
    while acquisition_running.value:
        length = 65536
        data = numpy.ndarray(length, dtype='float')

        data_queue.put(data)
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    acquisition_running = multiprocessing.Value(c_bool)

    data_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(
        target=run, args=(acquisition_running, data_queue))

    acquisition_running.value = True
    process.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    acquisition_running.value = False
    process.join()

    print('Finished')

    number_items = 0

    while not data_queue.empty():
        data_item = data_queue.get()
        number_items += 1

    print(number_items)
```

1. If I use `length=10` or so, everything works fine. I get 9 items transmitted through the Queue.
2. If I increase to `length=1000`, on my computer the `process.join()` blocks, although the function `run()` is already done. I can comment the line with `process.join()` and will see, that there are only 2 items put in the Queue, so apparently putting data to the Queue got very slow.

My plan is actually to transport 4 ndarray, each with length 65536. For the `Thread` this worked very fast (<1ms). Is there a way to improve speed of transmitting data for processes?

I used Python 3.4 on a Windows machine, but with Python 3.4 on Linux I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**"Is there a way to improve speed of transmitting data for processes?"**

Surely, given the right problem to solve. Currently, you are just filling a buffer without emptying it simultaneously. *Congratulations, you have just built yourself a so-called **deadlock**.* The corresponding quote [from the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms) is:

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
>   before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
>   “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe.

But, let's approach this slowly. First of all, "speed" is not your problem! I understand that you are just experimenting with Python's `multiprocessing`. The most important insight when reading your code is that the flow of communication between parent and child and especially the event handling does not really make sense. If you have a real-world problem that you are trying to solve, you definitely cannot solve it *this* way. If you do not have a real-world problem, then you first need to come up with a good one before you should start writing code ;-). Eventually, you will need to understand the communication primitives an operating system provides for inter-process communication.

**Explanation for what you are observing:**

Your child process generates about `10 * length * size(float)` bytes of data (considering the fact that your child process can perform about 10 iterations while your parent sleeps about 1 s before it sets `acquisition_running` to `False`). While your parent process sleeps, the child puts named amount of data into a queue. You need to appreciate that a queue is a complex construct. You do not need to understand every bit of it. But one thing really really is important: a queue for inter-process communication clearly uses some kind of buffer* that sits between parent and child. Buffers usually have a limited size. You are writing to this buffer from within the child *without* simultaneously reading from it in the parent. That is, the buffer contents steadily grow while the parent is just sleeping. By increasing `length` you run into the situation where the queue buffer is full and the child process cannot write to it anymore. However, the child process cannot *terminate* before it has written all data. At the same time, the parent process waits for the child to terminate.

You see? One entity waits for the other. The parent waits for the child to terminate and the child waits for the parent to make some space. Such a situation is called deadlock. It cannot resolve itself.

Regarding the details, the buffer situation is a little more complex than described above. Your child process has spawned an additional thread that tries to push the buffered data through a pipe to the parent. Actually, the buffer of this pipe is the limiting entity. It is defined by the operating system and, at least on Linux, is usually not larger than 65536 Bytes.

The essential part is, in other words: the parent does not *read* from the pipe *before* the child finishes *attempting to write* to the pipe. In *every* meaningful scenario where pipes are used, *reading* and *writing* happen in a rather simultaneous fashion so that one process can quickly react to input provided by another process. You are doing the exact opposite: you put your parent to sleep and therefore render it dis-responsive to input from the child, resulting in a deadlock situation.

(*) "*When a process first puts an item on the queue a feeder thread is started which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe*", from https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Doesn't really answer the OP's question.  But a darned good answer.

Comment: Okay, ironic answer: OP asks for how to improve "speed". That is his question, agreed? I give an explanation by which he/she can increase "the speed" by factor *infinity*: he currently has "speed" 0 (deadlock). Given the insight by which he resolves the deadlock, he/she obtains "speed" X. I think that pretty much addresses the OP's question :-). And I think we both agree that this OP had a misconception of "speed".

Comment: Nice pivot.  I agree.

Comment: First: Thanks for this really great answer. Obviously, I had a misunderstanding of how multiprocessing queues work, but I think I have a much clearer idea now. Actually, I want to use multiple processes to simultaneously read time traces into python and process them in parallel. Up till now I was using threads but they are not really multitasking, so I wanted to switch to processes. This code was just for testing and understanding the working principle of processes and queues, which apparently was necessary.

Comment: Just to follow up on this problem: Is there a limitation of how much data the feeder thread can hold, or will it just fill up till the memory is full and a MemoryError is raised? And does this limitation of 65536 Byte mean that any object that is going to be sent through the Queue (and underlying pipe) cannot be larger than 65536 Byte, or is the binary data streamed and the total object size does not play a role?

Comment: @erik: you do not want to try to launch too many multiple python processes simultaneously.  That would mean one python instance per process, and the overhead and memory requirements will likely bog you down -- especially if you are doing something quick like sending a single array element.

Comment: @erik, regarding limits: there are two buffers involved. **1)** A large buffer, part of the feeding thread (in the sending process): one would need to look into the source code for knowing how it really behaves. I guess it dynamically grows and may actually be as large as the system provides memory. This buffer limits the size of the objects that can be *put* into the queue. **2)** the pipe *capacity* (usually not called "buffer"). The pipe is used for streaming the contents of the first buffer to another process. It therefore does not limit the size of transferable objects.

Comment: @erik: *"I want to use multiple processes to simultaneously read time traces into python and process them in parallel"*: **Reading** in parallel and **processing** in parallel are two very different things. Depending on your problem, you might need only one of them, or indeed both. This depends on whether your problem rather is I/O-limited or CPU-limited, or both. Example: if you have only few data (say 1 GB) that takes ages to process on 1 CPU core but can easily be split into chunks and processed across multiple cores, you need **one** feeder and **multiple** consumer (worker) processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have really big arrays, you might want to only pass their pickled state -- or a better alternative might be to use `multiprocessing.Array` or `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` to make a shared memory array (for the latter, see http://briansimulator.org/sharing-numpy-arrays-between-processes/).  You have to worry about conflicts, as you'll have an array that's not bound by the GIL -- and needs locks.  However, you only need to send array indices to access the shared array data.

Comment: "your code will starting up like 1000 python instances.": Not true, he is calling `process.start()` only once.

Comment: Yeah, it helps to actually read the code instead of assume what the OP is doing.

Comment: And while you are right with your general recommendations, the problem in the OP's code is a different, but a very explanatory one. A good thing to fall for once, and to learn from this mistake :-).

Comment: Yeah, but I actually answered the OP's question… as opposed to stating why the code is wrong. ;)

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do to resolve that issue, in tandem with the excellent answer from JPG, is to unload your Queue between every processes.

So do this instead:

```
process.start()
data_item = data_queue.get()
process.join()
```

While this does not fully replicate the behavior in the code (number of data counting), you get the idea ;)

Answer (score -3):

Convert array/list to str(your_array)

```
q.put(str(your_array))
```